# number to grade letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iterator

As a recent assignment for my coding bootcamp, we've been asked to create a function that takes an array of numbers as an argument and outputs them to an array of letter grades. I am stuck!

I've tried re-working and refactoring my code, changing the placement of different parts of the program, looking through MDN...

```js
    let grades = []

    function getLetterGrades(grades) {
      let grade = grades.map 
      if (grade < 60) {
       return "F";
      } else if (grade < 70) {
        return "D";
      } else if (grade < 80) {
        return "C";
      } else if (grade < 90) {
        return "B";
      } else if (grade < 100) {
        return "A";
      }
      console.log(grades);
    }

    getLetterGrades([95, 85, 71]);
```

The results will only output the numbers I've entered into the function call.

Comment: `let grade = grades.map` so where is the function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: And what happens if someone **gets a score of 100**? Or even gets bonus points? You should work out the `100 <= grade` case too! :) (Or just add `90 <= grade` instead of `grade < 100` at the last **else if**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is this:

```
let grade = grades.map
```

You are not invoking the `.map` method with `()`, so instead `grade` is winding up holding a reference to the native `map` function. And, that function isn't a number, so none of your conditions become true, so you continue past the `if` statement and just log the array that you passed in.

Instead, you must invoke [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and supply its required parameter (a function that will be called for each item in the source array). Your `if` statement should be the body of that function:

```js
let grades = []

    function getLetterGrades(grades) {
      let letterGrades = grades.map(function(grade){
        if (grade < 60) {
         return "F";
        } else if (grade < 70) {
          return "D";
        } else if (grade < 80) {
          return "C";
        } else if (grade < 90) {
          return "B";
        } else if (grade < 100) {
          return "A";
        }      
      }); 

      console.log(letterGrades);
    }

    getLetterGrades([95, 85, 71]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) wrong. What you are doing is comparing the map method to a number. You are not executing anything.

```js
function getLetterGrades(grades) {
  return grades.map(function(grade) {
    if (grade < 60) {
      return "F";
    } else if (grade < 70) {
      return "D";
    } else if (grade < 80) {
      return "C";
    } else if (grade < 90) {
      return "B";
    } else if (grade < 100) {
      return "A";
    }
  });
}

var letters = getLetterGrades([95, 85, 71]);
console.log(letters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this solution:

```js
let grades = []

function getLetterGrades(grades) {
  // add an array (grade) that will hold the output
  let grade = []
  // iterate over grades with forEach()
  grades.forEach(item => {
    // item will be equal 95 on the first iteration
    // 85 on the second, and 71 on the third - these
    // values come from the passed 'grades' parameter
    if (item < 60) {
      grade.push("F");
    } else if (item < 70) {
      grade.push("D");
    } else if (item < 80) {
      grade.push("C");
    } else if (item < 90) {
      grade.push("B");
    } else if (item < 100) {
      grade.push("A");
    }
  })

  // console.log(grade) - NOT grades!
  console.log(grade);
}

getLetterGrades([95, 85, 71]);
```

The problem was not with the method you chose - the problem was you didn't finish your function. Here's another solution with `map()`:

```js
let grades = []

function getLetterGrades(grades) {

  let grade = grades.map(item => {
    if (item < 60) {
      return "F";
    } else if (item < 70) {
      return "D";
    } else if (item < 80) {
      return "C";
    } else if (item < 90) {
      return "B";
    } else if (item < 100) {
      return "A";
    }
  })

  // console.log(grade) - NOT grades!
  console.log(grade);
}

getLetterGrades([95, 85, 71]);
```

In this case the main difference between `forEach()` and `map()` is that `map()` returns a NEW array (that's why you `return` values in the function body), and `forEach()` doesn't (we had to create the array - `grade`- manually, and push values into this "hand-made" array).

Look below to see what would happen, if we used `forEach()` WITHOUT a manually created array:

```js
// THIS IS NOT A GOOD SOLUTION!
// IT GIVES YOU THE ANSWER IN THIS SMALL EXAMPLE
// (so you see that it's possible)
// BUT IN ANY LARGER CODE THIS IS THE
// 100% SURE SOURCE OF ERRORS.

let grades = []

function getLetterGrades(grades) {
  grades.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item < 60) {
      grades[index] = "F";
    } else if (item < 70) {
      grades[index] = "D";
    } else if (item < 80) {
      grades[index] = "C";
    } else if (item < 90) {
      grades[index] = "B";
    } else if (item < 100) {
      grades[index] = "A";
    }
  })

  // console.log(grades) - NOT grade!
  console.log(grades);
}

getLetterGrades([95, 85, 71]);
```

(I used the second argument of forEach() - that's index) **THIS IS NOT A GOOD SOLUTION!** Why? We "destroyed" our original `grades` array by overwriting it in `getLetterGrades()` - **DON'T DO THIS**!

Comment: You should try and explain how exactly it works it'd be more beneficial for the person asking.

Comment: Dear @DanielTurcich - I add the solution first, and then add the explanation. Look at the snippet now.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) takes a function and runs it once on each object in the array.  To be clear on how you're trying to use it:

```
function getLetterGrades(grade) {
  if (grade < 60) {
   return "F";
  } else if (grade < 70) {
    return "D";
  } else if (grade < 80) {
    return "C";
  } else if (grade < 90) {
    return "B";
  } else if (grade < 100) {
    return "A";
  }
}
x = [95, 85, 71];
//=> [A, B, C]
x.map(getLetterGrades);
```

Functionally, this is what the other answers are doing, they just aren't naming the method.

---

Post edited to change link as comment pointed out better resource.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stay as far away from W3Schools as possible. It's well-known to have incomplete, inaccurate, and/or out of date information. Instead, use the Mozilla Developers Network.